# Multi-Dimension Lists and Arrays

Tags: python, grid-search

i have decided to study Python. I am working on a framework that will support 3 sports manager games: Basketball, Hockey, Soccer.

After some reading (books, net, videos), i have decided to go with OOP (Class and Instances) to simulate my games. Even though i still need to read a bit, i understand the mechanics that will allow me to make something realistic. Now, i am thinking about how to make my players 'intelligent'. I would like to use various grids that will duplictate the playing surface. The first grid will be used to track the movement of the ball / puck, and the position of the players. This will be update in a class GamePlay. As for the decision making process of each player, i need them to look at where each players are, but also to consider their current assigment (offensive player, defensive player, left side defense, etc...). I would then need to create various grids with scores inserted into each box. I would probably need to have 15-20 such grids to make the game realistic. How should i go about it? I can create each grid into Excel and then export it into CSV files. But i would need to process them each time the program is running. Or should i create them manually i lists?

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy array to make a multi dimension array.

```
import numpy as np
array_ = np.zeros((20,10))
array_[1,5] = 50
print (array_)
```

You can assign anything to the elements of the array

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will read about them. This is what i need, i think. Then, should i use a csv reading loop to create them, each time the program is running, or should i take the time to input them manually once so it is in the program right at the get go? I have not yet understood the time required for a program to go through so much data.

Comment: I think you'd be best off having a look at a pygame tutorial to understand the logic behind it as I'm not sure what you are really trying to code at the moment. If you YouTube pygame tutorial just to get a better understanding of how all the parts will fit together.